# Как убавлять из цифры каждый день -1?

Tags: javascript

Есть структура

```
<div id='number'> 32</div>
```

Как сделать что бы каждый день он уменьшался на одну единицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
var StartAt = 0;
if(localStorage.getItem('StartedAt')==='undefined')
{
  StartAt = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000/86400);
  localStorage.setItem('StartedAt',StartAt );
} else
{
  StartAt = localStorage.getItem('StartedAt')
}
var MyDiv = document.getElementById("number");
MyDiv.innerHTML = parseInt(MyDiv.innerHTML) - (parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000/86400) - StartAt);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое Владимир